# kubernetes pod status check of a spring batch application

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, jenkins, spring-batch, kubectl

Have created a spring boot 3.0/batch application. The pod only gets created in Kubernetes for the duration of the batch processing and then exits (comes to completion status).

Currently using shell script(kubectl commands) invoked by Jenkins job to deploy the job.

At times, have seen the pod goes into error state(say within few minutes - exception scenario), but Jenkins job continues to run for the wait duration specified (below example for 2 hours).

```
kubectl -n ${NAMESPACE} apply -f deployment-jenkins.yml

# wait for completion as background process 
kubectl -n ${NAMESPACE} wait --for=condition=complete --timeout=2h job/${JOB_NAME}
```

Trying to find efficient way to periodically check for pod state (error/completed etc), so that can immediately exit with **0(success) or 1(error)** from script to pass/fail the Jenkins job in timely manner.